# Nesting Component gives Module Not found

Tags: angular, typescript

Cant get rid of this problem when I try to nest one simple table component to another.
This is the problem when I compile the file in vs code.

> ERROR in ./src/app/employee/employee.component.ts
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/employee/employee.component.html' in 'C:\Users\Ani\Desktop\Training\Angular\my-first-project\src\app\employee'.

This happens when I add EmployeeComponent in @NgModule.

This is my Code :
App.component.ts

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div>
                <h1>{{pageHeader}}</h1>
              </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  pageHeader: String = 'Employee-Details';
}
```

App.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './employee/employee.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, EmployeeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Employee.component.ts

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee',
    templateUrl: 'app/employee/employee.component.html'

})


export class EmployeeComponent {
    firstName: String = `Ani`;
    lastname: String = `master`;
    age: Number = 25;
    gender: String = `Male`;
}
```

Employee.component.html

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>{{firstName}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>{{lastName}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>{{age}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Gender</td>
        <td>{{gender}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change *absolute* path for the template or add a *relative* path. If they are in the same level, something like

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee',
    templateUrl: './employee.component.html'
})
```